# Cannot apply cursor pointer on a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to use `cursor:pointer;` on a wrapper div id=a, but when the user moves cursor on A or B, the cursor is set to default.

I need instead force the `cursor:pointer;` on all element inside the wrapper div so A and B.

I have tried to use z-index but with no success.

Any work around? (I need a CSS solution if possible)
Thank you very much.

```html
<div id="a" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:yellow; cursor:pointer; z-index: 100;">
A
  <div id="b" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; cursor:auto;">
    B
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:orange; cursor:auto;">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `inherit` instead of `auto`

```html
<div id="a" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:yellow; cursor:pointer; z-index: 100;">
A
  <div id="b" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; cursor:inherit">
    B
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:orange; cursor:inherit;">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Replace `cursor:auto` with `cursor:pointer`:

```html
<div id="a" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:yellow; cursor:pointer; z-index: 100;">
A
  <div id="b" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; cursor:pointer;">
    B
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:orange; cursor:pointer;">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `inherit` instead of `auto`

```
<div id="a" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:yellow; cursor:pointer; z-index: 100;">
A
  <div id="b" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue; cursor:inherit">
    B
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:orange; cursor:inherit;">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cursor: pointer;` for id `b` and `c` instead of `cursor: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

This will make `cursor: pointer` for all `<div>`s inside `id="a"`:

```html
<div id="a" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:yellow; cursor:pointer; z-index: 100;">
A
  <div id="b" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:blue;">
    B
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:orange;">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```